# Load table via list ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a table via post ajax, but it's not loading properly.

`table`:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped" id="tableestoque" style="font-size:12px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome Empresa</th>
                        <th>Qtd</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is how I am loading:

```
$.each(data.listaEstoque, function (i, item) {
                $("#tableestoque").append("<tr"
                    + "<td>" + item.empresaProduto.nome + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + item.qtd + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>")
            });
```

[image]

It is loading like this, I want you to load each one into a column, and if you have more rows, each in a row.

Comment: `$("#tableestoque").append("<tr"` => `$("#tableestoque tbody").append("<tr>"`. You are missing the `tbody` element and the closing of the `<tr>`.

Comment: just a typo - you missed the `>` from your `<tr`, should be `<tr>`

Comment: I think you need append you html to `<tbody>`, not to `<table>`

Comment: Not sure what you  mean by "clean only the tr".

Comment: @Deker I need to clear the included data, not the header

Comment: I got it sorted, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/g95vLp2h/2/) for you. Right now you are iterating over each element, not over each object. You should iterate over object using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) statement.

```
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Name1'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Name2'
}];
var $table = $("#tableestoque");
var $tr, $td1, $td2;

data.forEach(function(item) {
  $tr = $('<tr>');
  $td1 = $('<td>' + item.id + '</td>');
  $td2 = $('<td>' + item.name + '</td>');
  $tr.append($td1).append($td2);
  $table.append($tr);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to append your html to `<tbody>` like this:

```
$.each(data.listaEstoque, function (i, item) {
                $("#tableestoque tbody").append("<tr"
                    + "<td>" + item.empresaProduto.nome + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + item.qtd + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>")
            });
```

Comment: @Dekel users adding comments so fast. Sorry, If my answer give offense to you ;)